# How to provide Functionalty for Changing the Background Color of Text Parts in HTML Editor built with HTMLEditorKit

Tags: java, swing, htmleditorkit

My problem is as follows:

I want to enable the user of my little HTML editor to switch between
different background colors for the text being entered. I first tried
to use CSS styles for that purpose. The different styles define
different background colors and through a `JComboBox` the user could
switch between these styles. Upon selection of a style in the
respective position inside the `HTMLDocument` a new HTML element of type
`<span class="style">` would be entered.
Unfortunately I could not manage to get this work. The span elements
were simply not created ([see my question regarding this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793190/java-swing-css-style-attribute-class-use-in-htmleditorkit-htmldocument)).

In between I took a look at the class `StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction`
to learn how this functions.  Upon execution it simply modifies the
input attributes of the `StyledEditorKit` in use setting a new
foreground color. Text that is entered afterwards is displayed with
the new foreground color. And when writing the HTML code into a file,
the text is automagically enclosed in `<font color=".."> ... </font>`
HTML elements.  And all that even works on selected text which might
run over multiple paragraphs. In this case obviously the affected
text inside all affected paragraphs is enclosed into `<font ...>` HTML tags.

I want to accomplish the same functionality for setting the background
color on arbitrary chunks of text. But surprisingly this does not seem
to be so easy:-(

I didn't find a predefined action class for that purpose similar to the
`StyledEditorKit.foregroundAction` in the Java 7 JDK. Creating
such a class does not seem to be complex; it's almost the same as the
`ForegroundAction` with the `actionPerformed` method changed to set the
background instead of the foreground attribute.

But how to create valid HTML code that sets a specific background
color for parts of the contained text?
Until now I don't know which part of the `HTMLEditorKit` performs the
creation of all the `<font>` elements for text in the `HTMLDocument` that
has the foreground attribute set.  I think from the existing code
creating the `<font>` elements it should not be too hard to derive an
implementation that creates `<span style="background-color:...">`
elements instead of `<font>` elements for setting the background color
for arbitrary regions of text.  Or is all this already available and I
only didn't notice?  Any help would be appreciated!

In between I made a significant step forward and thanks to a piece of code found [here](http://svn.openmicroscopy.org.uk/svn/shoola/branches/ProtocolEditor/src/ui/components/htmlActions/InsertSpanAction.java)
I managed to create valid `<span>` elements. In the span elements I use the `class` attribute to assign a predefined style.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;

public class SimpleEditor extends JFrame {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final JTextPane   textPane;
    private final HTMLEditorKit edtKit;
    private final HTMLDocument  doc;
    private final StyleSheet predefStyles;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException, IOException {
        final SimpleEditor editor = new SimpleEditor();
        editor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        editor.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SimpleEditor() throws BadLocationException, IOException {
        super("Very Simple HTML Editor");
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        edtKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        textPane.setEditorKit(edtKit);
        predefStyles = new StyleSheet();
        predefStyles.addRule(".MyStyle1 { color:#cc0000; background-color:silver }\n" +
                             ".MyStyle2 { color:#0000cc; background-color:aqua }");
        doc = new HTMLDocument(predefStyles);
        textPane.setDocument(doc);

        final Container content = getContentPane();
        content.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.add(createToolBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
        setSize(500, 240);
    }

    private JToolBar createToolBar() {
        final Vector<String> styleNames = new Vector<String>();
        final Enumeration<?> names = predefStyles.getStyleNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            styleNames.add((String) names.nextElement());
        }
        final DefaultComboBoxModel<String> stylesModel =
                new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(styleNames);
        final JComboBox<String> cbStyleSel = new JComboBox<String>(stylesModel);
        final JToolBar bar = new JToolBar();
        Action dumpAction = null;
        for (final Action act : edtKit.getActions()) {
            if (act.getValue(Action.NAME).equals("dump-model")) {
                dumpAction = act;
                break;
            }
        }
        bar.add(dumpAction);
        cbStyleSel.setEditable(false);
        cbStyleSel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                e.getSource();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final JComboBox<CondStyle> cboStyleSel = (JComboBox<CondStyle>) e.getSource();
                final String selItem = (String) cboStyleSel.getSelectedItem();
                final MutableAttributeSet divAttributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                if (selItem.equals("default")) {
                    // This does not work!
                    final Style defStyle = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
                    divAttributes.addAttribute(HTML.Tag.CONTENT, defStyle);
                    textPane.setCharacterAttributes(divAttributes, true);
                } else {
                    divAttributes.addAttribute(HTML.Attribute.CLASS, selItem.substring(1));
                    final MutableAttributeSet tagAttributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                    tagAttributes.addAttribute(HTML.Tag.SPAN, divAttributes);
                    textPane.setCharacterAttributes(tagAttributes, false);
                }
                textPane.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        bar.add(cbStyleSel);
        return bar;
    }

    /**
     * Extracts the style attributes except the style's name
     * @param aStyle The style to be processed
     * @return The visual attributes extracted from the style
     */
    AttributeSet extractStyleAttribs(Style aStyle) {
        final MutableAttributeSet attribs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        final Enumeration<?> attribNames = aStyle.getAttributeNames();
        while (attribNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            final Object attribName = attribNames.nextElement();
            if (attribName == Style.NameAttribute) {
                continue;
            }
            attribs.addAttribute(attribName, aStyle.getAttribute(attribName));
        }
        return attribs;
    }

    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        final JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        final JMenu mnuFile = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(mnuFile);
        final SaveAction actSave = new SaveAction();
        mnuFile.add(actSave);
        return menubar;
    }

    class SaveAction extends AbstractAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public SaveAction() {
            super("Save");
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            if (chooser.showSaveDialog(SimpleEditor.this) != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                return;
            final File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            if (file == null)
                return;
            FileWriter writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(file);
                textPane.write(writer);
            } catch (final IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SimpleEditor.this,
                                              "File Not Saved", "ERROR",
                                              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } finally {
                if (writer != null) {
                    try {
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (final IOException x) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good! My only problem with this solution is that I couldn't manage to implement the switch back from text enclosed in `<span>` elements to "normal" text, i.e. text that is not placed inside of `<span>` elements.
This should be no big deal but unfortunately I couldn't figure out how I can accomplish that. Any ideas would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! And it's sooo simple;-)
To switch back from the styled text entry using `<span>` elements I only had to remove the `HTML.Tag.SPAN` attribute from the input attributes of the current text. This is accomplished as follows:

```
edtKit.getInputAttributes().removeAttribute(HTML.Tag.SPAN);
```

So the code for the ActionListener in the example code I posted in my (updated) question now looks as follows:

```
        cbStyleSel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            e.getSource();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final JComboBox<CondStyle> cboStyleSel = (JComboBox<CondStyle>) e.getSource();
            final String selItem = (String) cboStyleSel.getSelectedItem();
            if (selItem.equals("default")) {
                edtKit.getInputAttributes().removeAttribute(HTML.Tag.SPAN);
            } else {
                final MutableAttributeSet divAttributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                divAttributes.addAttribute(HTML.Attribute.CLASS, selItem.substring(1));
                final MutableAttributeSet tagAttributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                tagAttributes.addAttribute(HTML.Tag.SPAN, divAttributes);
                textPane.setCharacterAttributes(tagAttributes, false);
            }
            textPane.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    });
```

I had posted multiple questions regarding my problems implementing that functionality (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18016402/1549299), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17793190/1549299)) but got no answers. Maybe the issue was too trivial;-)